# FOS UserBundle new role

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new in symfony. I installed FOS userBundle and by default it has ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER. However I would like to have ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_EMP and ROLE_CLIENT.

Could anyone explain me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by "*it has*"`? Role is just a string. You can add any role you want.

Comment: dear dragoste. the security.yml is including role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: It's just inheritance configuration, not the roles itself. It's purpose it's to prevent to be required to grant e.g. both admin and user role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `FOS User Bundle` you just need to use a role to create it.

So, simply add your new roles to `security.yml` and/or to relevant users and they will exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help